# Debounce function on Scroll not working as required

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent

I am trying to limit the scroll events fired. I need it to happen only once in every one second. I achieved it to an extend. I am using debounce function which I got from this [Link](http://davidwalsh.name/essential-javascript-functions). It have a timer which is used to limit the event. On every scroll that i am doing, the timer is getting reset. But I want it like, the timer should only reset, once after the time specified (here 1 sec) is over after the previous scroll.

```
 function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};

// Usage
var scrollingFn = debounce(function() {
    // All the taxing stuff you do
    console.log('scrolling...');console.log('seperatr');
    document.getElementById('text').textContent += 'Scrolling...';
}, 1000, true);

window.addEventListener('mousewheel', scrollingFn);
window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollingFn);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/te3v720q/)

If you do continuously scroll in the demo, scroll event won't get fired even after 1 sec. Because timer is getting reset at every scroll. So It will take 1 sec from the last scroll happened within the time period.

My requirement is if I do a scroll, the timer should not get reset before 1 second. Please check the table below. I need it to work like this way.

```
=====================================================================
| Time   | Action   |     Result           |     Timer              |
=====================================================================
|0 sec   | scrolled | event should fire    | Timer Starts           |
|0.25 sec| scrolled | event shouldn't fire | Timer shouldn't reset  |
|0.5 sec | scrolled | event shouldn't fire | Timer shouldn't reset  |
|1.0 sec | scrolled | event shouldn't fire | Timer shouldn't reset  |
|1.1 sec | scrolled | event should fire    | Timer should reset     |
=====================================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `true` for the `immediate` parameter. That means the the function will run on the *first* event of a rapid sequence of events, which is exactly what happens in your demo program.

If you want the code to run *after* a sequence of scroll events, pass `false` instead of `true`.

Comment: I need it to run on the first event itself. and if am doing scroll for 1 sec after that nothing should happen. The next scroll should happen once 1 sec is completed.

Comment: @AjayVarghese OK, well that's not what that `debounce()` function was designed to do. It will either run the function when a series of scroll events **starts**, or when the series **finishes**, but not both.